# How to list by highest date in PHP

Tags: php

Hey guys so I am having some trouble using the following:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($noncompUsername); $i++)
{
    $tsql ="SELECT firstname,lastname,email,phone,statuschangedate FROM csvdata WHERE username = :username ORDER BY statuschangedate";
    $tgetmeminfo=$DBH->prepare($tsql);
    $tgetmeminfo->execute(array(':username' => $noncompUsername[$i]));
    while ($trow = $tgetmeminfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

        $csvFirst = $trow['firstname'];
        $csvLast = $trow['lastname'];
        $csvEmail = $trow['email'];
        $csvPhone = $trow['phone'];
        $csvDate = $trow['statuschangedate'];
        $timediff = strtotime($date) - strtotime($csvDate);
        $timediff = floor($timediff/86400);

        $sql ="SELECT MailingAdrs FROM insuranceverificationdisclaimer WHERE TraineeUsername = :tusername";
        $getmeminfo=$DBH->prepare($sql);
        $getmeminfo->execute(array(':tusername' => $noncompUsername[$i]));
        while ($row = $getmeminfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

            $csvAddrs = $row['MailingAdrs'];
            $change = 1;
        }
        if($change != 1)
        {
            $csvAddrs = "No address";
        }
        $change = 0;
        echo "$timediff, $csvFirst $csvLast, $csvEmail, $csvPhone, $csvAddrs";
    }
    echo "
    <br>
    ";
}
```

Now this works but the part I want to point out is the `$tsql ="SELECT firstname,lastname,email,phone,statuschangedate FROM csvdata WHERE username = :username ORDER BY statuschangedate";` - now when I do this and get the integer of the statuschangedate to the current date and print it out as an integer, it is not ordered properly based on the date.

So I need to get this to order by the oldest date on top and as follows...

Thank you!

David

Comment: If you want the oldest on top, your query seems to be doing just that.

Comment: But when I turn the dates into integers it tells me otherwise

Comment: So like lets say the status change date was from last week so it will check date from last week to now and turn that into an integer which is 7, so I will have 7's on top than 108 days in middle and just all over

Comment: Are you using a DATE type in the database for statuschangedate?

Comment: Hold on, what's `$date`? How is that defined?

Comment: $date = date("Y-m-d"); - statuschangedate is defined the same inside the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to order based on `$timediff` you should change the ORDER clause to this:

```
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(:date, statuschangedate)
```

Granted, this should actually give the same ordering you already had, but you could at least use this expression to save some processing in PHP itself :)

Comment: Did not work...what should :date be the $date I defined right?

Comment: @DavidBiga Yeah, that was the idea. Btw, are you saying that `$timediff` is all over the place?

Comment: No I am defining $timediff inside each iteration for each employee it associates with so I display the date difference in a list

Comment: @DavidBiga I know what the code does, I'm trying to establish from which value did you determine that the results are not properly ordered.

Comment: When I display the time difference allv the values down the list are not evenly in a decreasing value

Comment: @DavidBiga Well, you're processing them in a loop, so the user would be different each time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28280/discussion-between-david-biga-and-jack)

Answer (score 3):

Order the date in descending order (using `DESC`):

```
... ORDER BY statuschangedate DESC
```

Comment: Does not work for me I still have peoples dates that are turned into integers being 100 days or so when the top ones are 10 or 8